# Как спарсить ссылку?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Хочу сделать бот для скачивания клипов из платформы twitch.
На каждый клип есть ссылка в html коде, если по ней перейти то скачивается клип.
Например если перейти по этой [ссылке](https://production.assets.clips.twitchcdn.net/AT-cm%7CW6HbiglxguCaXSTXzDFXMQ.mp4?sig=032529ceb31e36d7808e998ad56daa01543986b4&token=%7B%22authorization%22%3A%7B%22forbidden%22%3Afalse%2C%22reason%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%22clip_uri%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fproduction.assets.clips.twitchcdn.net%2FAT-cm%257CW6HbiglxguCaXSTXzDFXMQ.mp4%22%2C%22device_id%22%3A%227rXahWtWfHbPGTBtti2Ubb7kufJBm0N4%22%2C%22expires%22%3A1654790048%2C%22user_id%22%3A%22476801891%22%2C%22version%22%3A2%7D)

То скачается [этот](https://www.twitch.tv/whoplohoyparen/clip/SmoothBoxyWitchJebaited-CXGC4JpdJNfMMVcx) клип.
Использую библиотеку beautifulsoup.
Пробовал через find.all.
Пробовал с помощью for el in select.
Перебрал почти все классы, но к успеху не пришел, подскажите как решить мою проблему.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
link = soup.findAll('div', class_='Layout-sc-nxg1ff-0 video-ref')
```

Comment: В ответ выдает такие скобки "[]", как это исправить?

Comment: див я примерно указал, попробуйте ввести то, к чему ссылка относится.

Comment: не работает, какой бы я див не взял. из-за этого и прошу помощи